# PASCAL : Get Length of array[x]

Tags: arrays, indexing, pascal, freepascal

How can I get the Length of an array with a specific index for example if I have an array like this

```
TYPE T_PERSON = PACKED RECORD
  Example : STRING[40];
  Example2 : STRING[10];
  Example3 : STRING[5];
END; 
example: ARRAY [1..30] OF T_PERSON
```

and I want to know the Length of `example[28]` respectively `example[x]`.
Can I get it with `LENGTH()` or is there another solution?

Comment: Do you mean [SizeOf](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/sizeof.html) function?

Answer (score 3):

If it is an array and you want the number of elements:

```
 high(example)-low(example)+1;
```

Afaik with Free Pascal and Delphi 4+ length might also work, but don't pin me on that.

If you need the size in bytes, Abelisto is correct and sizeof() is what you want, and it also works on parts of the record (e.g. sizeof(example.example)).

The sum might not add up though if you are not PACKED due to alignment bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can also get it with Length function.

```
function Length(A: DynArrayType):Integer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Every cell/element of your 'example' array has SizeOf(T_PERSON). This is the number of bytes.

As it stands, SizeOf(T_PERSON) is 58 bytes.

What I cannot explain is why it is 58 bytes and not 55 bytes (as I would expect it for non packed record) or even 56 bytes (for packed record aligned at 4-byte boundary).

Maybe someone else can shed some light on that.

Comment: Shortstrings like string[x] are prefixed with a length bytes. That makes 55 bytes character data + 3 x a length byte = 58 bytes.

Comment: I should have remembered that. Using 'array[x..y] of AnsiChar' gives exact sizes.